# Angular - two the same directives with different data - isolated scope

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

After my research I found out that I need to use isolated scopes in order to achive my goal.
Let me give you a little scheme how my application works now.

I have a webservice written in ASP.NET. I receive data in JSON using jQuery.ajax wrapped in a function:

```
function getData(id) {
    var params = { "PlannerId": id };
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Default.aspx/getData",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: JSON.stringify(params),
            dataType: "json",
            traditional: true,
            async: false,
            success: function (msg) {
                $scope.allSeminars = allSeminars.concat(msg.d.SeminarDays);
            }
        }); 
    return $scope.allSeminars;
}
```

The function is placed in the controller let's say "dataController".

Normally to display my directive once. I call my function (also in my controller) with some "id" i get from dynamic input.

`getData(jQuery('div[display-data]').parent().find('input').val());` and then call directive:

`<div display-data></div>` and it works for one data and one directive.

Now I want to display my directive twice on my webpage with different data in each.

I added isolated scope to my directive:

```
rfg.directive("displayData", ['someService', function (someService) {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        scope: {
            seminar: '=sem'
        },
        templateUrl: '../../template.tpl.html',
        controller: 'dataController',
```

Now I display my directive like this:

```
<div display-data sem="sem0"></div><br>
<div display-data sem="sem1"></div>
```

And my controller looks like this:

```
var semId = jQuery('div[display-data]');
$scope.sem0 = getData(jQuery(semId[0]).parent().find('input').val());
$scope.sem1 = getData(jQuery(semId[1]).parent().find('input').val());
```

I've also tried to add "seminar"(the one specified in directive scope) in the ng-repeat in my template but w/o success.

Does any1 has some clue what I'm doing wrong and also how can I replace get data from .ajax in different way than calling function responsible for that directly from controller.

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

I think your all logic is wrong, you should not use jQuery with AngularJS.

You can replace your `jQuery.ajax()` with `$http` or `ngRessource`

-> https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

-> https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource

Instead of doing this `jQuery(semId[0]).parent().find('input').val()` use `ng-model`

-> https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel

With that, you can start on good basis.